# Can't get uniqueness validation to work with activerecord-typedstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems

We're using the `activerecord-typedstore` gem at https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore which says "You can use any ActiveModel validator". I'm able to get `validates :name, presence: true` to work but `validates :name, uniqueness: true` gives me the error `PG::UndefinedColumn` (see below). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
class CreateWorkspaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :workspaces do |t|
      t.json :payload, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Workspace < ApplicationRecord
  typed_store :payload, coder: ActiveRecord::TypedStore::IdentityCoder do |s|
    s.string :name
  end
  
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

```
% rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> Workspace.create(name: 'Hello')
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Workspace Exists? (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "workspaces" WHERE "workspaces"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Hello"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
/Users/vince/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params': PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column workspaces.name does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "workspaces" WHERE "workspaces"."name" ...
```

Comment: `validates_uniqueness` *is not an ActiveModel validator*. Its a part of ActiveRecord and does simple SQL queries to check for the existance of records. It is not designed to deal with JSON/JSONB nonsense which requires a totally different query - neither should it be.  IMHO this is a clear cut example of the unneccisary JSON antipattern. If you can actually write model code that validates an attribute just use a normal column - and if uniqueness actually matters add a unique constraint to it. https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: If you do actually want todo this you would have to write a custom validator which does `where("payload->>'name' = ?",  name)`. But without a unique index its very prone to race conditions and its likely that you'll end up with duplicate data. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations#:~:text=Your%20Rails%20application%20probably%20makes,enough%20to%20ensure%20data%20integrity.

Answer (score 0):

I agree based on the comments that this isn't the best use of json as the column type in the example above. If you still want to do this, based on @max's comment add this file `models/concerns/hash_uniqueness_validator.rb`

```
class HashUniquenessValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    result = record.class.where("payload->>:attribute = :value", {attribute: attribute, value: value})
    result = result.where(options[:scope] => record[options[:scope]]) if options.key?(:scope)
    record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || "is not unique") unless result.count.zero?
  end
end
```

then you can do this

```
class Workspace < ApplicationRecord
  typed_store :payload, coder: ActiveRecord::TypedStore::IdentityCoder do |s|
    s.string :name
    s.string :url
  end
  
  validates :name, presence: true, hash_uniqueness: true
  validates :url,  presence: true, hash_uniqueness: { scope: :user_id)
end
```